# Statusbar color doesn't set properly on Meizu PRO 6

Tags: android, colors, background, statusbar

I got device-specific problem with Meizu PRO 6 / android 6.0

I try to set statusBar color by defining `colorPrimaryDark` in my theme file

When i set it to `#FF0000` (red) it works fine
[image: Meizu PRO 6 / #FF0000]

But when i set it to `#000000` (black) it doesn't apply (as you see, color is the same as `colorPrimary`)
[image: Meizu PRO 6 / #000000]

The same code run on LG Nexus 5x:
[image: Nexus 5x / #000000]

What could go wrong here? And how it can be fixed?

Suppose current device has some kind of color filtering for statusBar, maybe it allows only colors, that are lighter than `colorPrimary` or something like this...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Meizu has custom launcher and it's own implementation.

For me

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(color);
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
```

works ok. But when I tried to use it in activity that is not in focus yet It didn't work.

But this workaround (see snipet below) works . Just update colors when your activity has a focus

```
 @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
          //... your code for colorization
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm faced the same problem with `navigationBarColor` on OnePlus A6000 (6) / Android 9.
So, i just used 'almost' black color: `#010101`, and it works well!
I suppose, some phone manufacturers use `#000` (that is 0) as a default value, that points out the system to use app's primary color.